# Imagens estão repetindo nos ImageViews

Tags: java, android, random

Eu tenho 54 imagens preciso mostrar apenas 8, mas tem que ter uma seleção aleatória e não podem se repetir, estou programando na plataforma do Android Studio.

Eu uso esse código ele funciona tranquilo,Mostra os resultado em 8 `ImagemView` ,Mais.... ele repete os resultados da imagem ;(

```
insira o código aqui


public void Button2(View view) {

        final int[] imageViews = {
                R.id.imageView, R.id.imageView4, R.id.imageView7,
                R.id.imageView2, R.id.imageView5, R.id.imageView8,
                R.id.imageView3, R.id.imageView6,};


        final int[] images = {

                R.drawable.1,
                R.drawable.2,
                R.drawable.3,
                R.drawable.4,
                ...... vai até o 54


        };


        final Button shuffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Random generator = new Random();
                int n = 9;
                n = generator.nextInt(n);
                Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
                for (int v : imageViews) {
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(v);
                    iv.setImageResource(images[generator.nextInt(images.length - 1)]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

insira o código aqui
```

Usei este Código abaixo resolveu o problema.

};

```
final Button shuffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button4);
shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Random rng = new Random();
        List<Integer> generated = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            while(true)
            {
                Integer next = rng.nextInt(54) ;
                if (!generated.contains(next))
                {
                    generated.add(next);
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView)findViewById(imageViews[i]);
                    iv.setImageResource(images[next]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});}}
insira o código aqui
```

Fonte:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7470509/how-to-set-random-images-to-imageviews

Comment: Wallace este site funciona de forma diferente de um fórum, logo, você não precisa adicionar que foi resolvido no titulo. ao inves disso, você pode aceitar uma resposta como aceita, clicando no `v` ao lado da resposta. Dessa forma, é como se a pergunta ficasse marcada como "resolvida".

Comment: Engraçado, você respondeu sua pergunta na sua própria pergunta, que por ventura está bem parecido com minha resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer desta forma, comparando se o número gerado já existe no `ArrayList`:

```
int totalImagens = 54;
int totalEscolher = 10;
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Random randomGenerator = new Random();
while(numbers.size() < totalEscolher)
    {
        int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(totalImagens);
        if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
            numbers.add(random);
        }
}
```

Pensando desta forma, seu `setOnClickListener` ficaria assim:

```
final Button shuffle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button2);
        shuffle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int totalImagens = images.length;
                int totalEscolher = 10;
                final ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                Random randomGenerator = new Random();
                while(numbers.size() < totalEscolher)
                {
                    int random = randomGenerator.nextInt(totalImagens);
                    if (!numbers.contains(random)) {
                        numbers.add(random);
                    }
                }

                for (int v : numbers) {
                    imageViews[v] = images[numbers.get(v)];
                    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(v);
                    iv.setImageResource(imageViews[v]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela ajuda, mais como eu posso integrar esse código no meu projeto, desculpe mais não intendo muito. aguardo resposta, enquanto isso vou tentar implementar ele aqui.

Comment: @WallaceRoberto editei a resposta. Tente fazer desta maneira para ver se funciona.

Comment: Ta, e como eu faço agora na parte de cima, to pesquisando aqui sobre ArrayList mais sem sucesso, se você ver la em cima estou usando Imagens (R.drawable.exemplo) e a segunda linha ("final int[] imageViews = {")   ela continua?

Comment: @WallaceRoberto blz! Editei novamente para você. Agora pegando a imagem que está no seu images. Em cima você pode deixar da mesma forma inserindo as imagens.

Comment: Está dando erro, logo após apertar o botão.                                                  09-14 17:47:22.890 343-425/system_process W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger: setKernelCountSet(10054, 0) failed with errno -1